# How do I train and test data using K-nearest neighbour?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to train k-nearest neighbors.

I have a train data and a test data in two separate `.csv` documents, but most approaches I've seen use `train_test_split()`. I want to train on one document, and test on another.

My progress is below. I'm hoping to apply this to the [UCI Parkinson Speech Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+Speech+Dataset+with++Multiple+Types+of+Sound+Recordings) in case that's helpful.

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

iris.data = 'train_data.csv'
iris.target = 'test_data.csv'

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn.fit(X, y)

y_pred = knn.predict(X)
print(accuracy_score(y, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 1):

When train and test folds exist in separate files, the approach is similar.

Here's a short demo of this where we download `iris.data` from the UCI repository, rename the target column with `sed`, shuffle, and create `iris_train.csv` and `iris_test.csv` to each have 50 examples (setup based on [this blog post](https://hayesall.com/blog/knn-in-35-lines/)):

```bash
wget https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data
sed -i 's/Iris-setosa/1/g' iris.data
sed -i 's/Iris-versicolor/2/g' iris.data
sed -i 's/Iris-virginica/3/g' iris.data
sort -R iris.data > iris_random.data
head -n 50 iris_random.data > iris_train.csv
tail -n 50 iris_random.data > iris_test.csv
```

Meaning that our data is split between two files:

```
   iris_train.csv         iris_test.csv
4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2,1     6.1,2.9,4.7,1.4,2
4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,1     5.0,3.5,1.6,0.6,1
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,2     6.5,2.8,4.6,1.5,2
7.7,3.0,6.1,2.3,3     6.3,2.3,4.4,1.3,2
6.4,3.1,5.5,1.8,3     5.7,2.5,5.0,2.0,3
        (50 rows)             (50 rows)
```

Now instead of loading in a single file, we load two separate files containing our `train` and `test` data, then select columns for the respective `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test`, `y_test`:

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np

train = np.loadtxt("iris_train.csv", delimiter=",")
test = np.loadtxt("iris_test.csv", delimiter=",")

X_train, y_train = train[:, :4], train[:, 4]
X_test, y_test = test[:, :4], test[:, 4]

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
# 0.94
```

Comment: I got the error InvalidIndexError

Comment: Are you getting `InvalidIndexError` with exactly this code, or a different dataset? `train[:, :4]`, `train[:, 4]` is written for the iris dataset, where the first four columns contain variables, and the fifth column contains the target variable.

Comment: I used different dataset. The dataset has total 41 columns, among them 41th column is the class column. So I wrote the code `X_train, y_train = Training[:, :40], Training[:, 40]`
`X_test, y_test = Test[:, :40], Test[:, 40]`. I got `InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, 40, None))`

Comment: Oh, you're using pandas! Try something like: `Training.to_numpy()[:, :40]`. pandas and numpy use different selection and indexing approaches.

Comment: Now I got following error  `Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()`
`----> 1 X_train, y_train = Training.to_numpy[:, :40], Training.to_numpy[:, 40]`
     ` 2 X_test, y_test = Test.to_numpy[:, :40], Test.to_numpy[:, 40]`

`TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Careful: reread the previous message. Your version is missing: `()`

Answer (score 0):

in this code there are some things that are not correct .

1. Last line : plt is the abbreviation of matplotlib.pyplot, but you didn't import matplotlib and it is an error, to import matplotlib the code is the following one:

   import matplolib.pyplot as plt
2. Furthermore in order to predict Y value on test set, you have to use test set X values instead of training set X values;
3. Also you have to split X in X_Tr( training set) and X_Te( test set ) and similarly you have to separate Y values in two lists: YTr( training set) and YTe( test set ) .
   I hope I have been helpful .

Answer (score 0):

1- **Import** both csv files using `pandas.csv_read("/direction/to/it")`

2- **Merge** them together

for merging them you can use pandas capabilities like the following example from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [0, 1], "col_left": ["a", "b"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 2], "col_right": [2, 2, 2]})

pd.merge(df1, df2, on="col1", how="outer", indicator=True)

   col1 col_left  col_right      _merge
0     0        a        NaN   left_only
1     1        b        2.0        both
2     2      NaN        2.0  right_only
3     2      NaN        2.0  right_only
```

Now use `df.iloc["what_you_wish"]` and put in the input of `train_test_split`

Another way,however, is to just produce random indexes and use them instead of `train_test_split` but remember that you should consider classes as well or you would have unstandard data separation.